# Logarithmic advice language in P?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, advice-and-nonuniformity

Is something like DTIME(poly(n))/log(n) in P? Can the log-length advice be somehow hardwired into a DTM for P?

Comment: No, because P/log (or even P/1 for that matter) contains some undecidable languages.  Voted to close as off topic (too basic).

Comment: http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:P#plog

Comment: Tsuyoshi, while I don't disagree with your assessment that this is basic, it's helpful to then point the user to where they might find the answer (as Michael did).

Comment: @Suresh: At least I tried to be helpful by giving a brief explanation.  I think that my comment already contained some terms to search.  If you do not think that it was helpful, then we have simply different views about what is helpful.

Comment: Let me play the devil's advocate here: If we answer all basic questions in the comments before closing them, wont that encourage people to come here and ask basic questions? And surely there are at least 100 times as many people who would like to ask basic questions than research-level questions, so that would lead to this site being flooded with basic questions.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, @Suresh: I believe Tsuyoshi's comment was helpful, and it answered the OP completely. Yet a combination of Tsuyoshi & Michael's comment will be perfect: It answer's the question, AND points the OP to somewhere to read more.

Comment: @Robin: Maybe you're right. But I think even closing a question does not prevent users from commenting on them. Am I right?

Comment: @Robin: I am really afraid of that.  In fact, even as I was writing my first comment, I was afraid that it might be _too helpful_ (therefore Suresh’s comment and its four upvotes were least expected).  I usually do not answer the question when I vote to close, and I am not aware of any reason why I acted differently this time.  It is probably because it is Sunday today.

Comment: I think one solution is to answer an "induced" research-level question, as Sebastian Ben Daniel did below.  I learned something from his answer.  I also think that a lot of askers don't know whether their question is hard or easy, and they may not have a friendly neighborhood theorist to ask.  We've discussed this at length on Meta, and what I got out of it was: be as helpful as you can but don't help someone solve their homework problem.

Answer (score 9):

As pointed in the comments, You cannot do this in general,
However, if you're willing to restrict the class and add some some structure you can achive this. For example, you can use the self-reducibility of SAT to remove the advice, i.e if 
$NP\in P/log$ then $NP=P$.

In general, the same is true for complexity classes with self-reducible complete problem, and similar arguments for complexity classes with instance checkers $(EXP,PSPACE,P^{\#P})$ will allow you to remove even larger advices (polynomial) with the difference that now you need to use  probabilistic machines.

Comment: This is a nice answer.